# How to avoid duplicates in Einstein recommendations?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, content-builder, einstein-recommendations

If using 2 Einstein modules in an email, each with different logicIDs, is there a way to avoid the same product being populated?

For example, in the scenario below, the same cat product shows within both Einstein modules:

Module 1 (logicID 12345) - Dog product, cat product

Module 2 (logicID 67890) - Fish product, cat product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MC Einstein Email recommendations do not support multiple blocks for this reason - the blocks are processed independently and cannot be de-duplicated.

Comment: Thanks, Rick! I figured this was the case and am glad to have some outside confirmation.